# Google login on Android Webview is not showing accounts on device

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, webview, android-webview, google-signin

I have created an Android Webview using Android Studio (Java) and within it I am running my mobile responsive PHP website. I am facing this strange issue. On Chrome browser, when I try to login, I get all the Gmail accounts currently logged into my device. However, on my webview I am given with a fresh login screen where I need to enter my email id and password to proceed instead of allowing me to choose from the existing accounts. For clear reference, please checkout the screenshots below:

**My Android Webview (or even on Mozilla is the same result)**

[image]

**On Google Chrome**

[image]

Just like on Google chrome I want to have the accounts to be shown on my webview. But, I am not sure how to accomplish these as it works on chrome already but not on webview. Therefore, I am sure that the issue is not from the website's end. I need to make changes to my webview to get this. However, I am not sure what to do. Any guide will be appreciated. Thanks.